# howto get mouse coordinates in open select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouse

I know you can get the mouse coordinates within a browser window with for instance:

```
$(document).bind('mousemove',function(event) {
        X = event.pageX;
        Y = event.pageY;
        console.log(X+':'+Y);
})
```

This works in most cases but I currently have a case in which I can not use this.

I would like to also capture the mouse coordinates when a list of options in a select box is opened.

It appears that the 'normal' way of capturing the coordinates is terminated until the select box is closed again.

Is there a way to capture it?

Comment: Chrome (webkit?) browser doesn't handle any mouse event on `option` element inside `single` select

Comment: Which is working in Mozilla

Comment: You are right! I am testing it in Opera and Chrome in which it is not working. After your comment I tried it in Firefox and there I received the coordinates.

Comment: I have tried it on several ways. The last trial was by adding a transparent div on the page and capturing the coordinates from this div and sending the mouse clicks to the layer below. But this wasn't working either. I got the coordinates from the div and was able to send the clicks to the layer below but when the select opened I didn't receive any coordinates anymore :-(